# Conditional line breaks for contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I'm intercepting the return keypress on contenteditables and inserting two `<br>` tags instead of the default `<div>`. I'm adding two `<br>` tags because adding one doesn't move the caret onto a new line.

```
$(document).on("keydown", "[contenteditable='true']", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br><br>');
        return false;
    }
});
```

This works fine in most cases. For example, if I type

`This is some text`

then hit return, I get this

`This is some text
<br>
<br>`

Then if I type something, the last `<br>` is swapped out and I get this

`This is some text
<br>
Some more text`

Perfect. Except, if I move the caret back to the end of the first line and hit return, two `<br>` tags are added, jumping the caret down two spaces.

Is there some way to add the `<br>` tags conditionally, adding two only if the caret is at the end of the text range or something?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with introducing a new paragraph (`<div>`)? Does that have the cursor behaviour you'd expect?

Comment: I need the HTML to be as clean as possible because it will be downloaded and used by the user. Wrapping the <br> in a <div> etc. is just clumsy markup when all that's necessary is a <br> tag.

Comment: I guess cleaning up the HTML markup before download, instead of during editing, is the simpler solution then.